An SF novel with many characters among whom a "good one" and a "bad one"
I read this SF novel about 30 years ago, and it was possibly shortly after its first publication (in English).
It is a rich novel, with several threads that interact with each other, and many characters. But I have forgotten most of it. All I remember are two characters, a "good one" and a "bad one". (I'm not sure whether any of them is ugly).
The "good one" drives a motorcycle, and uses it, at the beginning of the novel, to bring pizzas to the people who ordered them, within a very short time. Then it gets more complicated.
The "bad one" is a ruthless killer. His preferred weapons are glass knives. They have the advantage to be carried through metal detectors without raising an alarm. Also, if the knife is lost or broken, he was able to make a new knife from any random piece of glass.
I hope this is enough...

This appears to be a mundane story about a pizza delivery man and an assassin who makes knives out of glass. What about it is science fictional or fantastical?

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40651883-snow-crash

Exactly @Valorum - so are you going to VTC?

@Valorum I did say I forgot most of this very rich story, and I did point out it was SF.

@ClaraDíazSanchez - I was planning to, but it was such an easy find and OP has confirmed that it is an on-topic novel, so it gets to stay open.

This is Snowcrash by Neil Stephenson.
One of the main characters uses glass knives to kill people.

In reality, Hiro Protagonist delivers pizza for Uncle Enzo's CosoNostra Pizza Inc., but in the Metaverse he's a warrior prince. Plunging headlong into the enigma of a new computer virus that's striking down hackers everywhere, he races along the neon-lit streets on a search-and-destroy mission for the shadowy virtual villain threatening to bring about infocalypse. Snow Crash is a mind-altering romp through a future America so bizarre, so outrageous… you'll recognize it immediately.

And

He is supported in this by Raven, an Aleutian psychopath with razor thin glass knives and a Nuclear Weapon strapped to his motorcycle, whose ambition is to destroy America in revenge for nuclear testing in his homeland. Raven is in league with some Russian religious fanatics.


Hiro Protagonist the Good, Raven the Bad, yes !
